# Проверить отсутствие WebElement на странице. Webdriver, Selenium, Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Нужно проверить, что на странице присутствует/отсутствует webElement.

Тест выполняется при проверке присутствия:
Assert.assertTrue(webElement.isDisplayed());

Но, почему-то валится при проверке отсутствия:
Assert.assertFalse(webElement.isDisplayed());

Не понимаю почему валится. Выдает ошибку NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть разница между "элемент есть на странице, но невидим" и "элемента нет на странице".

`isDisplayed` проверяет невидимость, элемент при этом должен быть на странице. Если элемента нет вообще (например, при поиске по id или css селектору), по попытка к нему обратиться, как в этом случае узнать видим ли он, приведет к исключению.

Таким образом если вас интересуют и случай когда элемента нет вообще и когда он невидим, то нужно делать как-то так:

```
boolean isDisplayed(By by) {
  try {
    return driver.findElement(by).isDisplayed();
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return False;
  }
}

Assert.assertTrue(isDisplayed(By.id('some-id')));
```